# Build/compile Resurrection Remix Nougat error

Tags: debian, android, compile, debian-wheezy, rom

I tried to build  Resurrection Remix v5.8.5 Nougat from source, but I get following  error:

```
. build/envsetup.sh && brunch hlte



Starting build with ninja

ninja: Entering directory `.'

ninja: warning: phony target '-*-' names itself as an input; ignoring [-w phonycycle=warn]

ninja: error: '/srv/2d8f112a-ce0d-4bbd-8948-25e9fb3fc9e4/git/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/lib/libtime_genoff.so.toc', needed by '/srv/2d8f112a-ce0d-4bbd-8948-25e9fb3fc9e4/git/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_servers_intermediates/LINKED/libandroid_servers.so', missing and no known rule to make it

build/core/ninja.mk:151: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed

make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

make: Leaving directory '/srv/2d8f112a-ce0d-4bbd-8948-25e9fb3fc9e4/git/RR'



#### make failed to build some targets (01:36 (mm:ss)) ####



No Jack server running. Try 'jack-admin start-server'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding:

```
<project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_samsung" path="vendor/samsung" revision="cm-14.1" remote="github" />
```

to
/srv/2d8f112a-ce0d-4bbd-8948-25e9fb3fc9e4/git/RR/.repo/local_manifests/roomservice.xml

Then execute

```
repo sync -j10 --force-sync
. build/envsetup.sh && brunch hlte
```